# ethernet port is not detected in freescale MPC8569 board after kernel updrade

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded

I have a freescale MPC8569 embedded board. previously, I put linux version 2.6.32 on it and all interface connected to processor are working properly.

Now, I upgraded my linux version to 3.10 and now Ethernet port is not working. This is output of my ifconfig command.

```
ifconfig eth0 up

[  745.019507] Unable to handle kernel paging request for data at address 0x00000000
[  745.027157] Faulting instruction address: 0x70411bec
[  745.032111] Oops: Kernel access of bad area, sig: 11 [#1]
[  745.037491] MPC8569 MDS
[  745.039924] Modules linked in:
[  745.042971] CPU: 0 PID: 998 Comm: ifconfig Not tainted 3.12.13-00010-g1cd7a83-dirty #9
[  745.050868] task: dfb51900 ti: dfbc4000 task.ti: dfbc4000
[  745.056248] NIP: 70411bec LR: 702adb9c CTR: 00000000
[  745.061196] REGS: dfbc5c80 TRAP: 0300   Not tainted  (3.12.13-00010-g1cd7a83-dirty)
[  745.068831] MSR: 00029000 <CE,EE,ME>  CR: 24002428  XER: 00000000
[  745.074920] DEAR: 00000000, ESR: 00800000
[  745.078913] 
GPR00: dfbc5d38 dfbc5d30 dfb51900 7055c56c dfa87e8d dfa87e2d 00000000 00000687 
GPR08: 00021000 00000000 71e041c0 70420fa0 24002424 1013c254 00000270 100d4410 
GPR16: 100d4500 00000238 00000000 4fe1b0d8 dfbc5e18 ffff8914 dfa06d00 dfa78000 
GPR24: 00000000 00000000 dfa06d0c dfbc5e08 7055c3e8 7055c570 dfb51900 7055c56c 
[  745.108562] Call Trace:
[  745.110997] [dfbc5d60] [702adb9c] 0x702adb9c
[  745.115252] [dfbc5d70] [702b6b4c] 0x702b6b4c
[  745.119508] [dfbc5d90] [70312770] 0x70312770
[  745.123763] [dfbc5db0] [7030f510] 0x7030f510
[  745.128019] [dfbc5dd0] [70311c24] 0x70311c24
[  745.132274] [dfbc5df0] [70369028] 0x70369028
[  745.136529] [dfbc5e60] [70369da8] 0x70369da8
[  745.140785] [dfbc5e70] [702fe1e4] 0x702fe1e4
[  745.145040] [dfbc5e90] [700d60a8] 0x700d60a8
[  745.149295] [dfbc5ea0] [700d6284] 0x700d6284
[  745.153551] [dfbc5f10] [700d691c] 0x700d691c
[  745.157806] [dfbc5f40] [7000d748] 0x7000d748
[  745.162062] --- Exception: c01 at 0xfe41718
[  745.162062]     LR = 0xfecaa24
[  745.169265] Instruction dump:
[  745.172219] 38000000 7d201828 7c00192d 40a2fff8 2f890001 419e007c 813f0008 38010008 
[  745.179957] 3bbf0004 901f0008 93a10008 9121000c <90090000> 93c10010 48000010 38000002 
[  745.187872] ---[ end trace 1ec9adc8d4459f31 ]---
[  745.192472] 
Segmentation fault
```

What points should be considered while upgrading my kernel version ?